# LMDE detects a wireless card, but can't use it

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint, debian-squeeze

LMDE can see my wireless card, and correctly identifies it, but it refuses to let me turn it on through the shiny graphical interface. Is there a way to use the non-shiny terminal to turn on my wireless?

One small tidbit I noticed was the stated version; it says the version is 00. I believe that's hexadecimal for 0, which may indicate something screwy with the software. It would be nice if someone could tell me how to figure out how to solve this kind of problem in the future.

```
*-network DISABLED
    description: Wireless interface
    product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
    logical name: wlan0
    version: 00
    serial: 91:e3:7b:0d:a3:a9
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-1-amd64 firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
    resources: irq:43 memory:e1d00000-e1d01fff
```

I've tested multiple other network managers, and none of them work. W ireless switch is on, I'm sure it's a driver problem.

Comment: Can you check whether `rfkill list` reports the device as blocked? (The version is just a number; nothing stops Intel from starting the count at 0.)

Comment: `    0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

I omitted the two entries for bluetooth. "rfkill unblock" does not appear to help, so I think it's a driver issue. @grawity

Answer (score 0):

A trip to Lenovo tech support told me to blacklist `amd_wmi`, which solved the problem. Lenovo's linux support is surprisingly good.